# Django not picking up changes to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get South to work - it worked fine on my PC, but I'm struggling to deploy it on my webhost.

Right now it seems that any changes I make to add/remove items from INSTALLED_APPS aren't being picked up by `syncdb` or `diffsettings`. I've added `south` to my list of INSTALLED_APPS, but the tables it needs aren't being created when I run `syncdb`. If I change other settings, they are picked up, it just seems to be INSTALLED_APPS that doesn't work.

If I run

```
from south.db import db
```

from the shell I get with `manage.py shell`, I don't get any import errors, so I don't think it's a problem with where `south` is. I've tried removing all my other applications (other than the Django standard ones), and tables for them still get created when I run `syncdb`.

Even if I delete INSTALLED_APPS completely, I still get the old list of INSTALLED_APPS when I run manage.py diffsettings.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Thanks,

Dom

Comment: I wonder if everyone else knows what **South** is?

Comment: south is an app that allows you to use migrations with Django - see http://south.aeracode.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is that I'm a moron. I'd done this:

In `settings.py`:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
)
...

from localsettings import *
```

In `localsettings.py`

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
)
...
```

I'd created `localsettings.py` from `settings.py`, to contain things only relevant to the current location of the project (like database settings), and forgot to delete the `INSTALLED_APPS` section.

Apologies for doing such a flagrantly stupid thing.

Comment: oops!!! I guess that was the reason, the management command "migrate" was unknown. Coz south wasn't found in installed apps tuple.

Answer (score 3):

If you write a migration for an application, syncdb wont work.
You have to use

```
manage.py migrate
```

syncdb wont work for applications which are hooked under migration using south. Those applications model change will be noticed only depending on south migration history.

[South Migration Docs](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/Documentation)

Comment: That doesn't work, because south is not being picked up as being an installed app, so I get: Unknown command: 'migrate'.

Comment: Thanks for the try though - +1ed